# Object to String. How?

Tags: php, oop, object

I've did some research. I've found that you can serialize then unserialize to get a string... but I want a better solution.

I got an object array returned by IMAP pear module (`function imap_getmailboxes`).

```
public function GetMailBoxes(){
    $List = imap_getmailboxes($this->Link, '{'.$this->Server.':'.$this->Port.'}', '*');

    $Data = array();
    if(is_array($List)){
        foreach($List as $Key => $Value){
            $Value = unserialize(serialize($Value));
            $In = strpos($Value->name, '{');
            $Out = strpos($Value->name, '}');

            $Part = substr($Value, $Out);
            $Value->real_name = explode($Value->delimiter, imap_utf7_decode($Part));
            $Value->real_name = (isset($Value->real_name[1]) ? $Value->real_name[1] : null);

            $Data[$Key] = $Value;
        }
    }

    return $Data;
}
```

The problem here is strpos tell me this `Warning: substr() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in /home/david/domains/davidbelanger.net/public_html/panel/drivers/mail.php on line 178`.

How Can I transform the object into a string ? Any idea, never done this before.

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you doing `$Value = unserialize(serialize($Value));`?  That line is completely useless, remove it.

Comment: @Rocket Please read my first line. This is why it was there in first place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think instead of

```
$Part = substr($Value, $Out);
```

you want

```
$Part = substr($Value->name, $Out);
```

Comment: Damm, I've missed that. Thanks so much... so stupid ! I think I need to go bed.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the magic method `__toString()`

As noted here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.tostring

Comment: KingCrunch found the problem here, but thanks for pointing that out. It will help me in the near future. Thanks a lot.